What is the constant in the proof of $D(f) = O(N^0(f) \cdot N^1(f))$
In the book Communication Complexity by Eyal Kushilevitz and Noam Nisan, there is a proof that
$$
D(f) = O(N^0(f) \cdot N^1(f)),
$$
where:

$D(f)$ is the deterministic communication complexity of $f$,
$N^0(f)$ and $N^1(f)$ are the non-deterministic communication complexities of $f$ for outputs 0 and 1, respectively.

I would like to know what is the constant hidden in the $O$-notation of this proof? Is this constant greater than 1? This is relevant to determine whether the following inequality holds:
$$
D(f) \leq (N(f))^2,
$$
Is there another way to bound $D(f)$ in terms of $N(f)$ without involving a constant factor?
Any clarification or additional insight would be greatly appreciated!

See Theorem 13.3.2 here: https://lovasz.web.elte.hu/kurzusok/complexity.pdf for the cited theorem and a bit better upper bound right after.

@domororp That looks like an answer.
